# C# How to allow my textbox.text to accept more than one digit

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, I am trying to implement the below code, but noticed that only one digit is accepted by the textbox.text though declared as int

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int RegionIDInput;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out RegionIDInput))
        {
            if (RegionIDInput > 254 || RegionIDInput < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter valid value");
                RegionIDInput = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Numeric Value");
        }

     }
```

Comment: Note that the code converts the text twice. Remove `RegionIDInput = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: Are you trying to make a numeric textbox that accepts value only between 1 and 254?

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly

Comment: Rohit, Yes i want to check the textbox value ranges only between 1 to 254 if it is any value other than the range the format of output would be different, I have written a separate function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event is fired on every char that the user has entered, that's the reason for the issue. You can handle the `Leave` event:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int RegionIDInput;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out RegionIDInput))
    {
        if (RegionIDInput > 254 || RegionIDInput < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid value");
            this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Numeric Value");
        this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
    }
}
```

Note that your code converted the text twice. So i've removed the redundant  `RegionIDInput = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: You should consider to set the focus back on the textbox when the messagebox disappears so user can directly enter text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable textBox2 initially:

```
this.textBox2.Enabled = false;
```

Then change the first text box Leave event handler like this:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int RegionIDInput;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out RegionIDInput))
    {
        if (RegionIDInput < 1 || RegionIDInput > 254)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid value");
            this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Numeric Value");
        this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
    }
}
```